# Stacking images over each other issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to stack all the bigger images over each other and have the thumnails right underneath it.

I did that using:

```
#images img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

But the issue is that the thumbnails move to the top of the page. How can I have the thumbnails be below the big images and have the big images be stacked.

PS: I would rather not use margin-top

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <div id="images">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/360x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+01" alt=""/>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/360x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+02" alt=""/>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/360x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+03" alt=""/>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/360x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+04" alt=""/>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/360x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+05" alt=""/>
    </div>

    <div id="thumbnails">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/360x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+01" alt=""/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/360x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+02" alt=""/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/360x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+03" alt=""/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/360x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+04" alt=""/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/360x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+05" alt=""/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#gallery {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
}
#thumbnails {
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 800px;
}
#images {
    width: 770px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#thumbnails img {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
}
#images img {
    border: 4px solid #555;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 750px;
}
#thumbnails a:link, #thumbnails a:visited {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    border: 6px solid #555;
    margin: 6px;
    float: left;
}
#thumbnails a:hover {
    border: 6px solid #888;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gjz193Lt/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use floats, fixed position, or absolute position, an element is removed from the static flow of the page layout and it no longer contributes to the calculated height of the parent element. When floats are the issue, we can use a clearfix but with absolute positioning you need to set a height on the container.

To solve this In your example, we know the size of the images so I just added `height: 630px;` to `#images` after including the absolute positioning you were hoping to use for stacking the images.

P.S. I also added -5px margin to the left and right of `#thumbnails` to counter the outer margins of the first and last thumbnails to align it horizontally with `#images`.

```css
#images img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

#gallery {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
}
#thumbnails {
    margin: 10px -5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 800px;
}
#images {
    width: 770px;
    position: relative;
    height: 630px;
}
#thumbnails img {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
}
#images img {
    border: 4px solid #555;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 750px;
}
#thumbnails a:link, #thumbnails a:visited {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    border: 6px solid #555;
    margin: 6px;
    float: left;
}
#thumbnails a:hover {
    border: 6px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
    <div id="images">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/360x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+01" alt=""/>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/360x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+02" alt=""/>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/360x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+03" alt=""/>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/360x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+04" alt=""/>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/360x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+05" alt=""/>
    </div>

    <div id="thumbnails">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/360x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+01" alt=""/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/360x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+02" alt=""/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/360x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+03" alt=""/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/360x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+04" alt=""/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/360x300/000/fff.png&text=Image+05" alt=""/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign some width and height to `#images` div, and then assign `max-width` and `max-height` to 100% for the `#images img` and make their position `absolute`. The div containing the absolute imgs should have some height.

Like this:

```
#gallery {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
}

#images {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
#images img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

#thumbnails {
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 800px;
}

#thumbnails img {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
}
```

One of the best resource to learn CSS positioning is at http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/